# Compare-Object Pass Into Get-ADUser To Get DisplayName

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, compareobject

Good day. What I am trying to accomplish is showing the DisplayName as well as the Name but the only thing I can get to show with `Compare-Object` is Name so I am trying to pass the output from `Compare-Object` into `Get-ADUser` to get more user information. Below is the code that I am working with.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory #imports AD module
$group = Read-Host "What is the group name that you want to get membership for?"
$list = Get-ADGroupMember $group -recursive | Select Name

$OU = Read-Host "What is the OU that you want a list of? [List full path {OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx}]"
$OUList = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -Filter * -Properties Name, DisplayName, Title | Select Name

$Comparison = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $list -DifferenceObject $OUList | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Select Name
ForEach ($user in $Comparison) {Get-ADUser $user.InputObject -Properties Name,DisplayName | Select Name, DisplayName}
```

The error I get is

> Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value
>   "@{Name=*username*}" to type
>   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser

I know this is probably something simple but I can't quite figure it out. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: What happens when you use `$name` instead of `$name.InputObject` in `Get-ADUser`?

Comment: I get the same error except instead of saying "Cannot convert value @{Name=*username*}" it says "Cannot convert value @ {Name=}".

Comment: You didn't expand name so `Get-ADUser $user.InputObject` - > `Get-ADUser $user.name` Or you could expand name in your select: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` and then just use `$user`

Comment: Thank you BenH! That worked very well.